# How do I make the for loop use a new list that was made with the if statement

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, nested

This is my code:

```
the_list = ['Lily', 'Brad', 'Fatima', 'Zining']

for name in the_list:
    print(name)
    if name == 'Brad':
      the_list = ['Tom', 'Jim', 'Garry', 'Steve']
    else:
      continue
```

How do I make it so that the for loop now runs through the new list

I know I could just make a new for loop in the if statement but that's not what i want it to do.

Comment: try out recursion

Comment: what do yu want exactly, stop the currrent iteration on the first list, or first go through all the first list, then the second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a recursive function:

```
def check_the_list(x):
    for name in x:
        print(name)
        if name == 'Brad':
            check_the_list(['Tom', 'Jim', 'Garry', 'Steve'])
        else:
            continue


the_list = ['Lily', 'Brad', 'Fatima', 'Zining']

check_the_list(the_list)
```

> OUT: Lily Brad Tom Jim Garry Steve Fatima Zining

Or stopping after checking the other list:

```
def check_the_list(x):
    for name in x:
        print(name)
        if name == 'Brad':
            check_the_list(['Tom', 'Jim', 'Garry', 'Steve'])
            break
        else:
            continue


the_list = ['Lily', 'Brad', 'Fatima', 'Zining']

check_the_list(the_list)
```

> OUT: Lily Brad Tom Jim Garry Steve

Comment: btw your `else: continue` is redundant.

Comment: it definetely is! I just tried to solve the question the OP had, and touch the code the least so that OP can see what is the actual change relevant to the question. But yes, thx!

Comment: Yes, that's fine. I usually do that as well. Just a note for all the future readers who come across this answer.

Comment: perfect! ------